# Why SVPullToRefresh is not triggered

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, pull-to-refresh

I am new to iOS programming. I am adding SVPullToRefresh to one of my `TableViewController` instances, it looks very simple, only takes several lines of code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak MyMainTableViewController *weakSelf = self;

    [self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
        [weakSelf loadNotes];
    }];

    ...
}
```

But when I try it in the simulator, nothing happens. The action handler doesn't get triggered.

Where did I do it wrong? I am developing on iOS7.

Comment: Try it in the `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Jkmn Thank you very much. it's working in `viewWillAppear`. Why is that? I saw the author did that in `viewDidLoad` in the Demo project.

Comment: I guess you are using autolayout, it's probably a problem with constraint being calculated and overwriting the contentInset added by `addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler`.

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout, so it's also a good place to handle `SVPullToRefresh` in `viewDidAppear` or there's a better way?